# Make a bounding box for raphael svg path

Tags: jquery, html, svg, raphael, draggable

I am using raphael.js(2.1.2) and raphael.sketchpad.js to be able to draw svg paths.
I wish to use getBBox to **make bounding boxes** around svg paths so that I can apply various operations( select, drag ) on it.

Following is the code that is generated when I draw a small line

```
    <svg height="7866" version="1.1" width="857" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg_id" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 3; pointer-events: visiblepainted; left: -0.09375px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: text;">

    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;"></desc>

    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;"></defs>

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M160.90625,62L160.90625,63L162.90625,65L162.90625,70L163.90625,74L163.90625,
76L163.90625,78L163.90625,79" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; 
stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; -webkit-user-select: text;"></path>

    </svg>
```

My question is how can I make bounding boxes for each svg path element in the first place?
Also where will it be made? If I want to make paths draggable will making bounding box help me in any way?

Any help will be really appreciated !!

Comment: I think you can use canvas element for it.

Comment: It will be made wherever you place it, assuming you create it yourself with Raphael (use getBBox, then s.rect() from its values). I think you need to put a jsfiddle up of your js/raph code to make the question clearer. I don't see how a bounding box will help you drag an element (unless you want to drag via a bounding box). Just attach a Raph drag handler to the path.

Comment: Thanks Ian Li, I now understood that bounding box cannot help me drag. However I have achieved selecting the svg path element.